# How to edit a Range programmatically in Monaco Editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm creating a number scrubber for Monaco editor. To do so I need to be able to programmatically edit a range in the code. I can create a range using `new monaco.Range(1, 1, 1, 1)` and I can then get the text from the range using `editor.getModel().getValueInRange(myRange);`. However I can't figure out how to edit a range.

The EditOperationBuilder was the only thing I could find in the docs (https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/editor.IEditOperationBuilder.html) which is maybe what I want, but I can't find any examples online of how to use it. And when I try using IEditOperationBuilder with my version of Monaco Editor v0.41.0 it seems that IEditOperationBuilder doesn't even exist as a property of the global monaco object, the editor, or the editor model. I also checked and there is no `setValueInRange` method which would be intuitive given that there is a `getValueInRange` method.

Answer (score 1):

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/editor.ICodeEditor.html#executeEdits
example:

```js
editor.executeEdits('number-scrubber', [
  {
    range: new monaco.Range(1, 1, 1, 1),
    text: code,
  },
]);
```